# How to find the log diff of data values on Excel?

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm currently looking to run a MLR on GDP: quarter on quarter growth. I’ve been asked to find the log diff of the gdp, however I’m unaware on how to do this on Excel and how to account for negative values. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It may be helpful if you could make the title of your comment more informative and relevant to others who may have as similar question.

Comment: @beeguy Ive edited the question, in future how would you advise on how to make my questions better to understand, thank you.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to explore our [help].  Some advice on asking questions appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking.  Also see our [Meta thread on avoiding poor questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175).